# How to make it possible to send sms via the emulator?

Tags: java-me

I want to test my application which sends a sms. How to enable that with the Sun Java ME Platform SDK 3.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [discussion](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?157508-Send-and-Recieve-SMS%28WMA%29-in-emulator-in-j2me) on nokia forum.